# To which should I give the secret manager permission?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to give the permission to access the secrets manager

```
const rdsKeySecretArn = resourceName.rdsKeyInfos()['arn'];
const rdsKeySecret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretCompleteArn(this, 'SecretFromCompleteArn', rdsKeySecretArn);

rdsKeySecret.grantRead(cluster)// fargate cluster 
rdsKeySecret.grantRead(ecsAdminService) //service
rdsKeySecret.grantRead(taskDefinitionAdmin) // taskdefinition
rdsKeySecret.grantRead(djangoContainer) // container
```

`grantRead` shows  the error

```
Argument of type 'Cluster' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IGrantable'
```

I try `service`, `taskdifinition` and `container`.

However they show the same error.

How can I solve?

Comment: Thank you for your help . I review the past articles and check which I miss to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question directly, you should grant it to the task role:

```
rdsKeySecret.grantRead(taskDefinitionAdmin.taskRole);
```

The task role is what the containers running in the task assume when they call AWS services.

That being said, the better way to do this is to pass the secret via environment variables using the [`secrets` prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.ContainerDefinition.html#secrets) with [`Secret.fromSecretsManager(rdsKeySecret)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs.Secret.html#static-fromwbrsecretswbrmanagersecret-field)

This will not expose the secret, it will resolve and pass it to the container at runtime. CDK will create the appropriate permissions automatically

Comment: Thank you I researched around and found.  it has excutionRole and taskRole. ANd your further explanation is very useful for my next step. I will try new one.